# Correctly set marks for unnumbered chapters and sections with titleps

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{myps}[\sffamily]{
  \sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle~\thechapter]  % even
          {\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage} % odd
}

\pagestyle{myps}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\chaptermark{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The marks in the second page of the `Acknowledgements` chapter still prints as `Acknowledgements 1`, i.e. they print the chapter number of the previous one.

What I'de need to get is `Acknowledgements` on the headers, without any chapter number, since the chapter is unnumbered.

How to get the expected behavior?

Comment: Could it be because the contents of both chapters is the same? ;o)

Comment: I don’t think the content of the chapters have anything to do with the headers marks

Comment: Starred sectioning commands do not set marks. You have to set it manually: `\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\chaptermark{Acknowledgements}`. But the wrong chapter number still remains.

Comment: Ok, I was missing that, but then how can I detect in the head that the current chapter is unnumbered and avoid printing the number?

Comment: @esdd: The problem is that `titleps` *normally* doesn't use marks.

Comment: I've edited the question to better reflect my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution consists in redefining `\titleformat{\chapter}...` and using the `numberless` key to have different `\chaptermark`s for numbered and unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[pagestyles, explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\chaptermark{#1 \thechapter}\bfseries}{\huge\chaptername \thechapter}{4ex}{\Huge#1}%
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\chaptermark{#1}\bfseries}{}{0ex}{\Huge#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{myps}[\sffamily]{%
  \sethead[\thepage][][\chaptertitle]% even
          {\thesection~\sectiontitle}{}{\thepage} % odd
}

\pagestyle{myps}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{A test section}
\lipsum[3-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 But I think, `~\ifthechapter{}{\thechapter}` should be removed. In the example it inserts only a space. `\ifthechapter` seems to be a test, if counter `secnumdepth` is at least `0`.

Comment: @esdd: You're right. It's the remnants of a first trial (without using `\chaptermark`) wich didn't produce anything useful. Actually, I don't fully understand how this test works, and looking at the code details in the package didn't help.